How to declare parameters to be passed on to STL algorithms/std::transform_reduce?
I have many integer values. In several places, I want the sum of the halves of a contiguous bunch of them, differing from half the sum by the effect of truncation.
For all the examples of use of transform_reduce with lambdas, I can't seem to figure out how to declare parameters to be passed on to transform_reduce().
static long int
sum_halves(?1 first, ?2 exclude) {
    return std::transform_reduce(first, exclude, 0L, std::plus, [](auto v){
            return v / 2;
        });
}

How should I declare parameters to be passed on to std::transform_reduce  as first and last?

While I don't readily see how any of the answers to How does STL algorithm work independent of Iterator type? applies, it got me guessing.
Turning the function into a template function seems to work:
template <typename iter_type>
static long int sum_halves(iter_type first, iter_type exclude) {
    return std::transform_reduce(first, exclude, 
        0L, std::plus<long>(), [](auto v) {
            return v / 2L;
        });
}


(It can't be auto - or can it?)

It can be auto - which will make sum_halves a template in disguise. Or you can declare template yourself. Or you can declare specific type if you know this function is to be called with one type of container only (e.g., only with std::vector<int>).

Still don't know whether this is the way to go. Once I get the whole shebang looking half decent, CODE  REVIEW@SE may clue me in,

Conspicuously auto does allow different iterator type, e.g. value.cbegin(), values.end(). And the compiler dutifully balks when passing these to std::transform_reduce()…
